# spawned child_process stdout to 'readline' without buffering in node?

Tags: node.js

When I run myProgram from the command line, the output shows up in real time as it is being generated. When I spawn it from node like this, the stdout buffers and comes out one big chunk at a time.

```
const bat = require('child_process').spawn('myProgram', []);
bat.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
bat.stdout.on('data', console.log);
```

How can I tell child_process not to buffer stdout? Or set the buffer size smaller?

NEXT ATTEMPT:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var options = {
    stdio: ["ignore", process.stdout, "ignore"]
};

const bat = spawn('myProgram', [], options);

const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log(line);
});
```

This prints `process.stdout` to the terminal but `readline` does not get the data even though the [documentation says](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) `process.stdout` "...is a Duplex stream..."

Comment: Try replacing that entire block of code with `require('child_process').spawn('myProgram', { stdio: ["ignore", process.stdout, "ignore"] })`

Comment: Thanks - that works to pass unbuffered to the console. What I actually need to do is stream into 'readline'. Can that be done unbuffered?

Comment: Specifically, the stdio arguments can be a "tty, file, socket, or a pipe" stream. How can I create a stream that will work there and will let readline spit out a line as soon as it arrives instead of waiting for a big buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's easiest to let `spawn` create a new stdout stream, and pass that into `readline`:

```
const bat = spawn('myProgram');
const rl  = require('readline').createInterface({ input: bat.stdout });
```

**EDIT**: okay, the issue isn't so much Node, but C/C++ stdout buffering. If you pipe the output of your program through `cat`, it also won't show the output when it's generated:

```
./main | cat
```

Since you have the code, the easiest fix would be to disable buffering on `stdout`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

Alternatively, call `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf()`.

Comment: The output from 'readline' comes many lines at a time after being buffered. How can I force 'readline' to emit a line every time one comes out of myProgram?

Comment: What OS are you using? I tested with various programs that output lines and "sleep" in between, and each line gets picked up by `readline` the moment it's generated. What happens when you pipe the output of the program you're running through something like `cat`? Perhaps the output of the program behaves differently when it's connected to a pipe instead of a terminal.

Comment: OSX 10.11.6 / Node 5.0.0

Comment: And what's the program you're trying to run? Can you reproduce the issue with other programs as well? (I'm on basically the same OS so it's easy enough to test)

Comment: It's a sample c++ program from the NITE library (detecting gectures from the kinect camera). It prints updated coordinates to the console and I am trying to stream those to a websocket broadcaster with node. https://github.com/jbeuckm/kinect_websocket_server

Comment: What's interesting is that I can give spawn { stdio: ['ignore', process.stdout, 'ignore'] } and the streaming works flawlessly to the console.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me , hope its of help

```
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
   const {chunksToLinesAsync, chomp} = require('@rauschma/stringio');

   var options = {
    stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", process.stderr]
};
   console.log("Here is the complete output of the program: ");
   
   var child = spawn(i, [],options);
   echoReadable(child.stdout); // (B)

  console.log('### DONE');

  async function echoReadable(readable) {
    for await (const line of chunksToLinesAsync(readable)) { // (C)
      console.log('LINE: '+chomp(line))
    }
  }
```